# Issues with Html table rows on print when page breaks

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, printing

I have a table with large number of rows which can span multiple pages  during printing. I am having a few issues getting the table to render correct on page breaks.

The first issue is that I have my thead repeating on every page but sometimes it so happens that it prints it to the last row of the previous page and at times just writes over the last data row.

Another issue I'm having is that I have top and bottom margins set as 1cm on the page but the rows disappear beneath the margins. So, if I have the last row on the previous page as row 18, I get row 21 on the next page. Rows 19 and 20 disappear beneath the margins.
This is the margins css:

```
  @page {
      size: auto;
      margin: 1cm 0;
  }
  @page:first {
    margin: 0;
  }
```

If I don't use @page:first, then the 2nd issue about rows disappearing beneath margins gets fixed but I do not need margins on the 1st page.

This is the css relating to my table:

```
 table { page-break-after:auto }
  tr    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto;}
  td    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto; }
  thead { display:table-header-group }
```

I'm using chrome for this.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `border-collapse: collapse;` to `<table>`. Worked for me for whatever reason.